# unable to open the downloaded excel birt report through maximo

Tags: birt, maximo

Birt Report consist a simple created SQL query based report using date paramater which is having two section one is SR Details and second is section deals with Worklog.

After running on to the production and downloaded in excel format, I am unable to open the report in excel format.

Here is the error as follows
AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.MSO\64385E05.log

Answer (score 0):

"AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.MSO\xxxxxxx.log"

This error cause to due to excel installation,after changing the registry on installation path with 0, now its opening the excel report.